# Can I get() an R global environment variable by reference?

Tags: r

I have 21 global environment variables each containing large amounts of data. I want to access these variables by reference within functions, but I want to paramaterize their names so for example if I have SPdata, NEdata, FRdata etc.... 21 variables, I would like to know how to access them within functions by passing only the "country name" (ie "SP, "NE", "FR" etc) *without* having to create a copy(because they're each over 300 meg in size). Get seems to make a copy (inefficient for my size of data). Can I do this? I am currently using gets everywhere so

```
cData <- get(paste(cCode, "data", sep = ""))
```

Yes I know I should have put them all into a list in the global env but it's too late now and I don't want to refactor all the code. It's just that my "gets" are becoming memory inefficient, and multiple access in loops could be slow. Could I for example access each variable as if it were in a list?

I should have gone with countryData = list(SPdata, NEdata, FRdata..etc), accessing them with countryData[[paste(cCode, "data", sep = "")]] but it's too late now.

I should have added that I do intend to change some values within functions and get() does copy on change, as is visible from the different addresses below.

```
> .Internal(inspect(a))
@101b7bcf8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
> g <- function() {x <- get("a"); x; x <- 2; .Internal(inspect(x))}
> g()
@101cea648 14 REALSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
>
```

Comment: In the example .Internal(inspect(x)) is issued after assniging a new value to `x` and that was what caused the new address -- not the `get` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get` does not generate copies.   For example, in the code below we see that `x` is *not* a copy of `a.1` since its at the same address i.e. at  `0x00000000077a0010` .

```
> a.1 <- 1:1000000
> .Internal(inspect(a.1))
@0x00000000077a0010 13 INTSXP g0c7 [NAM(1)] (len=1000000, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
> g <- function() { x <- get("a.1"); .Internal(inspect(x)); max(x) }
> g()
@0x00000000077a0010 13 INTSXP g0c7 [NAM(2)] (len=1000000, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
[1] 1000000
```

If you modify a variable (appending is a type of modification) then it will be copied. Here `x` started out at `0x00000000075b95d8` but after being modified was copied to `0x000000000744d8e0` and after being appended to was copied yet again this time to `0x000000000754c5e8` :

```
> n <- 10000
> x <- 1:n
> .Internal(inspect(x))
@0x00000000075b95d8 13 INTSXP g0c7 [NAM(1)] (len=10000, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
> f <- function() {
+ .GlobalEnv$x[[n]] <- 0
+ .Internal(inspect(x))
+ x <<- c(x, 0)
+ .Internal(inspect(x))
+ }
> f()
@0x000000000744d8e0 14 REALSXP g0c7 [NAM(1)] (len=10000, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
@0x000000000754c5e8 14 REALSXP g0c7 [NAM(1)] (len=10001, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
```

Above we modified the global variable from within the function but even if we had done it outside the function it still would have been copied.

Comment: I have modified my question which was incomplete. I do need to make small changes (appends). I know there is an environment hack for passing by reference but I would rather avoid hacks.

Answer (score 4):

Quick ones:

- R semantics are 'copy on write', so if you don't alter the content of these variables, no copies are being made
- R has memory profiling, are you actually sure copies are being made? See 'Writing R Extensions' for the basics on the memory profiling.
- If you really are sure that these are being copied, you could prevent this by forcing external pointer use, either by using XPtr objects or by using wrappers deploying external pointers such as bigmemory.

Comment: okay I'll take a look. I have assumed that copies are being made because if I do this: dd <- 1; ee <- get("dd"); ee <- 2, then dd is still equal to 1. Also I do need to write to these variables so I'm currently writing to the copies, then assigning them back to overwrite the originals.

Comment: Dirk: wouldn't the `<-` be the function responsible for the copy?

Comment: No, copy on write -- just re-assigning works with a reference. See Gabor's answer for details -- if you did `a.2 <- a.1` you'd still use the same memory address.

Comment: The problem is the copy on write. I unfortunately do need to make small modifications to the global variables.

Comment: So external pointers it is. And I fear you do need to rewrite your code for that.  You may want to consider external storage too -- maybe even a cache / fast NoSQL db like Redis (which is very easy to access from R via rredis).

Comment: Redis again eh! I think I must get into it. Seems the right way to go for data storage and sharing.